# Max user sessions per user - apache shiro

Tags: java, authentication, shiro

I have configured **Apache shiro** and it works fine with my application.

Now i need to configure max sessions per user, meaning one user cannot login into another machine or if he tries to login, it should invalidate its previous session or maybe he cannot login with new session.

At single point of time, there should only be one user session.

**LoginServlet**

```
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username , password);
org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
subject.login(token);
loginSuccessful = true;
token.clear();
```

**Configuration xml**

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    </bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="shiroCacheManager" />
        <property name="realm" ref="myRealm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="shiroCacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager">
    </bean>

<bean id="myRealm" class="com.mypackage.service.shiro.RoleSecurityJdbcRealm">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="shiroDatasource" />
        <property name="permissionsLookupEnabled" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need implement doAuthenticate(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) from Class ModularRealmAuthenticator and throw ConcurrentAccessException if you find another active session for this user.

All active sessions can be obtained from

Collection activeSessions  = ((DefaultSessionManager)SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager()).getActiveSessions()

Comment: i will try as suggested by you

Comment: `getActiveSessions() ` is protected inside `DefaultSessionManager`, how to go about this..??

Comment: I am using `DefaultWebSecurityManager`

Comment: Extend DefaultSessionManager and make it public :) and set it as session manager in shiro.ini or calling SecurityManager.setSessionManager during loading.

Comment: i have added my configuration xml in question, i am using `DefaultWebSecurityManager ` and then configuring my `realm`

Comment: `<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="shiroCacheManager" />
        <property name="realm" ref="myRealm" />
  <property name="sessionManager" ref="ankurSessionManager" />
    </bean>
 
<bean id="ankurSessionManager" class="com.ankur.AnkurSessionManager"> <!-- AnkurSessionManager extends DefaultSessionManager-->
</bean>`

Comment: tried with this approach, registered the `DefaultSessionManager ` bean, and just overrided the method in `public class CustomSessionManager extends DefaultSessionManager {

 @Override
 public Collection<Session> getActiveSessions() {
  return super.getActiveSessions();
 }
}`

But it does not log me into application now. Do i need to override any other methods also.

Comment: Did you set CustomSessionManager as sessionManager for securityManager? If yes and still login is not happening then see is it set properly by checking SecurityUtil.getSecurityManager().getSessionManager() instance is CustomSessionManager.