# I am developing Spring Rest appliction multiple session management for same username and password

Tags: java, spring-rest

I am developing Spring Rest appliction, want to maitain multiple session of same username and password. When I logged out from one another should be not be invailidated.

Comment: Did you try using session-management.concurrency-control ? Tutorial : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session

Comment: I using shiro for security and HttpSession,HttpSessionListener for session management.

Comment: And did you try to use the concurrency-control setting? Did you read that tutorial?

Comment: concurrency-control from shiro or J2EE or Spring ??

Comment: Sorry, that's a Spring setting. Ok, Shiro, what exactly doesn't work in your implementation? From this SO post [1], I understand that, by default, multiple sessions per user are allowed... [1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826410/max-user-sessions-per-user-apache-shiro/37850497#37850497